# Java Exchanger example not working

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have following code.The code creates two runnables with messages "Hello" and "World" respectively. 
I expect this to exchange "Hello" with "World", but it does not work. The code gets stuck and the exchange never happens

Changed the code as follows. It works now

```
public class ExchangerExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Exchanger<String> exchanger = new Exchanger();

    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            String message = "Hello";
            Object previous = message;
            message = exchanger.exchange(message);
            System.out.println(previous + " is changed to " + message);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            String message = "World";
            Object previous = message;
            message = exchanger.exchange(message);
            System.out.println(previous + " is changed to " + message);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

Comment: your program work fine with me it print `World is changed to Hello 
Hello is changed to World`!

Answer (score 0):

first of all this is not a good design for writing such program , looks like spagetti code , first write a `ExchangerRunnable` class :

```
public class ExchangerRunnable implements Runnable{

    Exchanger exchanger = null;
    Object    object    = null;

    public ExchangerRunnable(Exchanger exchanger, Object object) {
        this.exchanger = exchanger;
        this.object = object;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Object previous = this.object;

            this.object = this.exchanger.exchange(this.object);

            System.out.println(
                    Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                    " exchanged " + previous + " for " + this.object
            );
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use it as written bellow :

```
Exchanger exchanger = new Exchanger();

ExchangerRunnable exchangerRunnable1 =
        new ExchangerRunnable(exchanger, "Hello");

ExchangerRunnable exchangerRunnable2 =
        new ExchangerRunnable(exchanger, "World");

new Thread(exchangerRunnable1).start();
new Thread(exchangerRunnable2).start();
```

the output will be :

```
Thread-0 exchanged Hello for World
Thread-1 exchanged World for Hello
```

any problems ?

Answer (score 0):

In this quiz your main doesn't wait for background threads, and they can be interrupted before exchanges. Add this:

```
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
```